# How to make character sprint AS3

Tags: debugging, keyboard, key, delay, conditional-statements

The code is for sprinting on a character. If the user presses the right arrow within x ticks after the first tap it will make object move faster.

The user has limited time to press again. When time runs out it should reset.

By pressing the right arrow key the timer starts ticking, and it keeps ticking even with no key being pressed (if user presses again within this time the object will move faster) - When it comes to 0, if not pressed, it should reset boolean variables back to false, but it isn't doing so.

In the function onKeyUp, the if below should be true

So, tap once then leave it:

```
function onKeyUp ... //no key being pressed
//leave it until timer reaches 0.
if (timer <= 0) {
TimerCounter = false;
condition1 = false;
condition2 = false;
timer = 5;
```

Copy and paste the code below, run it and see the trace. If you tap right arrow once and release, even when timer gets to 0 it will say

*Timer:  0;
Condition 1:  true;
Condition 2:  true;*

When it shouldn't.

```
package 
{

(...)

public class Main extends Sprite 
{

var player:Sprite = new Sprite();
var keys:Array = [];
var sprint:Boolean = false;
var condition1:Boolean = false;
var condition2:Boolean = false;
var TimerCounter:Boolean = false;
var timer:int = 7;

public function Main():void 
{

player.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
player.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 25);
player.graphics.endFill;

addChild(player);
player.x = 100;
player.y = 100;

player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);
}

function getBack (e:Event) {
player.x = 100;
}

function update(e:Event) {
  trace("Timer: ",timer);
  trace("Condition 1: ", condition1);
  trace("Condition 2: ", condition2);
  if ((TimerCounter)&&(timer > 0)) {
    timer --;
    condition1 = true;
  }

if (keys[Keyboard.RIGHT]) {
  TimerCounter = true;

  if ((condition1)&&(condition2)) {
    sprint = true;
  }

  if (sprint) {
    player.x += 7;
  } else player.x += 1;
}

function onKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
  keys[e.keyCode] = true;
}

function onKeyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
keys[e.keyCode] = false;

if ((condition1)&&(timer>0)) {
  condition2 = true;                
}

if (sprint) {
  TimerCounter = false;
  condition1 = false;
  condition2 = false;
  sprint = false;
  timer = 7;
}

if (timer <= 0) {
  TimerCounter = false;
  condition1 = false;
  condition2 = false;
  timer = 7;
}
} //onKeyUp function end.
} // Class end.
} // package end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `onKeyUp` *doesn't* mean the key is not being pressed.  This is only fired once, when the key is released, not fired constantly as implied in your question.  You need to check in a different function.

```
function onKeyUp ... //key is released
//leave it until timer reaches 0.
if (timer <= 0) {
TimerCounter = false;
condition1 = false;
condition2 = false;
timer = 5;
```

Options:

- You could check it in the `update` function instead, and then add an additional boolean to `onKeyUp`/`onKeyDown` to see if the key is actually pressed (tell whether or not to increment the timer).
- You could also just use `keys[e.keyCode]` event to check to see if the key/which key is down.  The key here is that you can't keep the timer check in the `onKeyUp` event because it is only called once per key up/down, *not* whenever the key is up.

Comment: Thank you! - That was part of it, however, I'd rather be working with miliseconds for timings of this sort, as what I intend to make involves lot of key combination and timings, ("2nd key must be pressed within x secs after 1st key" type of thing)... Should I use delay thingy?